# Changing color of lines of a echart

Tags: javascript, typescript, echarts

I have a line chart which has default line colors. I know that I can change these colors by changing "lineStyle" option, however I want to make these changes according to a selection from the UI. For this, I'm using "selectedColor" field which changes according to the selection. The problem is that my chart is not refreshing after each change. How can I achieve this dynamic coloring?

```
this.genericChartOptions = {
series: [
{
  name: 'Line 1',
  type: 'line',
  lineStyle: { color: this.selectedColor },
  smooth: true,
  data: [0.02, 0.03, 0.09, 0.1, 0.08, 0.15, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.2],
},
{
  name: 'Line 2',
  type: 'line',
  smooth: true,
  data: [0.12, 0.2, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8],
  markArea: {},
},
],
};

onChange(value: string) {
  this.selectedColor = value;
}
```

Comment: you should call setOption after change